# Not asking you to solve but I'd like some pointers on error 6842

Tags: search, error, administration

Google search didn't yield anything fruitful.
I think it's because if I configured the way most formally trained developers do, they *know* you have to do x,y, and z. Whereas I have 0 knowledge and am doing by trial and error.

Anyhow..
Application Log gave:
 EventData

string0 Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance 
  string1 1880d451-ff61-4b40-8070-3abe2e71e5fe 
  string2 I/O error occurred. 
  string3 System.IO.IOException: **I/O error occurred**. at

- Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
  at
  Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean
  isAdministrationServiceJob)

What I bolded, Google gave even fewer results when I included that in my search.

I'm thinking the problem has to do with what I underlined.
I am having troubling understanding what in the world the search server instance synchronization is trying to access/do with the provisioned local shared service instance (and I have no idea what I just typed means).

Again, not asking you to do this for me but please point me to the correct area in central administration or the relevant technet articles that I should familiarize myself with in order to find out what they are so I can move forward in fixing.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem? From your write up I have no idea what is wrong aside from the error message.

Comment: This is user66128. Since I have <50 reputation I can't respond to your comment so it looks like I'm resigned to responding by posting an "answer". I have no idea what the problem is. I have 6842 showing up in Application log every minute for the past week and ALL of them show only that. What I copy and pasted is from "Details" under "EventData". The only other info event log provides is system info. &nbsp; I paid more attention to the log and what I find strange is that ALL of them list my farm admin account as the user under "General". May not help but "Task Category: Shared Services" Maybe t